# deselect a selected item of a multi-select box under a certain condition

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I'm trying to figure out how to deselect a selected item of a multi-select box if another option is chosen. In the following scenario I just want the option 'admin' (default value) to be deselected if any of the other options (or all of the other options) are chosen.

*Simply: Admin is selected by default, if the user selects 'user' or 'editor' or both, admin should deselect.*

Currently, it doesn't deselect.

```
    $('#groups').on('change', function () {
        var selected = $('#groups').find('option:selected').val();
        console.log('selected: ' + selected);
        // if anything other than admin is selected deselect admin
        if (selected !== 'admin') {
            $('#admin').prop('selected', false);
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="groups" multiple>
        <option value="admin" selected="selected" id="admin">Admin Only</option>
        <option value="user">User</option>
        <option value="editor">Editor</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What is groups variable? Console.log your selected let see what is he retrieving

Comment: my bad i change the code so that it was smaller for stack. the variable just referenced the groups selector `$('#groups')`. i've updated it now.

Comment: So you want only one selection at a time?

Comment: No, then I would just use a regular select box. Basically admin is selected by default, if the user selects 'user' or 'editor' or both, admin should deselect.

Comment: So if he selects both `user` and `editor` or any one `user` or `editor` then admin should deselect?

Comment: Yes! That is correct. Would just prefer if I didn't have to saying if either user or editor is selected then deselect admin, instead should be if anything else is selected deselect admin as more options might be added.

Comment: Are you using which jQuery version?

Comment: i dont see how that matters but the latest one

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can loop through the `select options` and when the `select option` with the value `"admin"` comes, then you can uncheck it by setting the selected property to false.

---

```js
$(function() {


  $('#groups').on('change', function() {

    let selected = $('#groups').find('option:selected');

    selected = Array.from(selected);

    console.log(selected);

    if(!(selected.length == 1 && selected.value == admin))
    {
     selected.forEach(item => {
     if (item.value == "admin") 
        {
        item.selected = false;
     }
     });
   }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

  <select id="groups" multiple>
        <option value="admin" selected="selected" class="optionValue">Admin Only</option>
        <option value="user" class="optionValue">User</option>
        <option value="editor" class="optionValue">Editor</option>
</select>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

---

Comment: This doesn't really work. Hit ctrl and select 'admin' and 'user'... 'admin' doesn't deselect

Comment: It works now! I prefer my version as it has less code, but upvote for the effort!

Comment: @Alex can you check now?

Comment: i did! see prev comment!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
groups.on('change', function () {
    // if anything other than admin is selected deselect admin
    var selected = groups.find('option:selected');
    console.log('selected: ' + selected.val());
    if (selected.val() == 'admin' && selected.length == 1) {
        $('#admin').prop('selected', true);
    } else {
        $('#admin').prop('selected', false);
    }
});
```

`groups` is just an alias for the selector.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#groups').on('change', function () {
    var values = $(this).val();
    var new_values = [];
    if ((values.includes('user')) || (values.includes('editor'))){
        for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
          if (values[i] !== 'admin'){
            new_values.push(values[i])
          }
        }
        $(this).val(new_values);
    }
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="groups" multiple>
        <option value="admin" selected="selected" id="admin">Admin Only</option>
        <option value="user">User</option>
        <option value="editor">Editor</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but I prefer the solution I found as it involves less code! Upvoted for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Deselect selected option included below with jQuery 2.2.4 version which I have tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select class="form-control" id="groups" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="admin" selected="selected" id="admin">Admin Only</option>
                <option value="user">User</option>
                <option value="editor">Editor</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
$('#groups').on('change', function () {
    var selected = $('#groups').find('option:selected').val();
    console.log('selected: ' + selected);
    if (selected == 'admin') {
        $("#groups > option:selected").attr("selected",false);            
        $('#groups > option[value="admin"]').prop('selected', true);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: this code always selects admin no matter what. this is the opposite of what I am trying to achieve...

Comment: Now modified some changes in script

Comment: Hit ctrl and select 'admin' and 'user'... 'admin' doesn't deselect